# team=liste[1] IndexError: list index out of range error

Tags: python

```
with open('C:/Users/murat/Desktop/futbolcular.txt','r') as file:   

  for i in file:

    i=i[:-1]
    liste=i.split(',')
    name=liste[0]
    team=liste[1]
```

my futbolcular.txt

Fernando Muslera,Galatasaray
Atiba Hutchinson,Besiktas
Sener ozbayrakli,Fenerbahce

Comment: print `liste` before attempting to index it, and you'll probably spot your error. There is most likely a line, empty or otherwise, that does not have a `,` in it, leading to only a 1 length `liste` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a *newline* in your file, and that gets picked up as an explicit and empty line. And the result of the split is thus a one-element list. You need to filter out empty lines. Also please follow python coding conventions:

- use 4 spaces to indent
- don't use single-character variable names

  ```
  with open('C:/Users/murat/Desktop/futbolcular.txt','r') as file:   
      for line in file:
          line = line.strip() # gets you rid of unwanted whitespace
          if line:
              liste = line.split(',')
              name, team = liste
  ```